# Custom URL making- URL rewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, subdomain

My URL is "http://properties.Poject.net/Public.aspx?account=ACCOUNT&id=HL101"

and my desired URL is http://properties.Poject.net/ACCOUNT/HL101

Please help me to achieve this. ALso i don't have URLWrite option in my IIS 6 and my project is under .net 3.5. Please help me config in Web.config

Thanks.
Manu

Comment: Which version of .net you are using????

Answer (score 1):

Use the concept called Url Routing in asp.net

refer article

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use the following two links, it briefly describe how to apply url Routing,by the way URL routing is more advance concept then URL rewriting  so use that.....

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx